# Passing 00 in json gives bad request

Tags: python, json, rest

when i try to pass

```
{
    "features": {
        "ABC": 00,
        "CBK": 3.1,
        "HUF": 16,
        "XYZ": 70
    },
    "id": "70a"
}
```

my POST request is not sent to the API and json gives me 400 bad request error

How do i parse the 00 value to my python script

```
self.features = request.get_json()['features']
```

Comment: Show how you're passing the object in the POST request.

Comment: @Barmar: i'm using POSTMAN for sending the request. I have posted the request in my question.

Comment: `00` is not a valid JSON value.

Comment: using string quote maybe?

Comment: @KlausD.: yes i'm aware of this, but i need to pass 00 as integer. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can not do that in JSON as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not consider 00 as a number. As you see in the below picture taken from https://www.json.org/json-en.html,  if the datatype is number, JSON technically looks for anything between 1-9 or a dot(.) in case of a decimal.

So, the solution to your problem is that you either need to convert the datatype of the values to be string and enclose them in "" or you make the JSON builder that you are using to pass in the value as 0 instead of 00.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need 00 instead of 0? If you need to retain it, you could set it as a string otherwise it will just be evaluated as 0.

Comment: The features input can be an int or float, how do i convert it back from string to their original form once received in the python script